# I hope you will be happy with what you get or I hope you are happy with what you will get?

Tags: sentence-choice

Which one is correct?

- I hope you will be happy with what you get.
- I hope you are happy with what you will get.
- I hope you will be happy with what you will get.
- I hope you are happy with what you get.

The context:

When I say this to a friend, he is going to receive a gift from me but he haven't got it yet.

Comment: The second one suggests that he knows in advance what the gift is, so he's happy now. Assuming he doesn't know, I would use the first or last. (Yes, I know the last uses the present tense too, but here it implies the future.)

Comment: Given the exact context, I'd say only #1 makes sense. Native Anglophones *don't* usually repeat the future tense in such contexts, so #3 just sounds like something non-native speakers might say. And it makes no sense to hope someone ***is*** happy with a situation they don't yet know.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea of the four sentences is the same. Your friend will probably understand what you mean whichever one you use. But grammatically I think (1) is the best match with what you want to communicate.

The main idea of the sentence is your desire for the other person to be happy.  Now this happiness is in the future. (It will happen at the point when a gift is given, and that moment is in the future.)

The second part of the sentence is the clause "with what you get." The hope is that the getting  and the happiness will occur at the same time. This is why I would say "with what you get" (present tense in relation to "be happy"). If you say "with what you will get" you create a second future tense event, and that raises the question: how do the two future tenses relate to each other?

For example, Sentence 3 ("I hope you will be happy with what you will get.") probably means the same as sentence 1. But it could mean, "I hope you will be happy tomorrow with what you will get next month." Sentence 1 is clear.